# Variable not being assigned unless it is assigned within the method that accesses it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sheep inherits from an Animal class.The following should call Sheep's Attack() method, which is a Debug.Log() that displays the animalName variable.  Instead, Unity displays nothing.

If I move the declaration of animalName into the Attack() method, it works, but for some reason it doesn't assign animalName if it's located in the class itself but not the called method.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animal Animal;

    void Update () {

        Animal.Attack();

    }
}
```

And here is the Animal object that is not working.

```
public class Sheep : Animal {

    string animalName = "wot";

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log(animalName);
    }
}
```

Here is the animal class that Sheep inherits from:

```
public abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour {

public int hpMax;
public int power;
public int defense;
public int speed;
public string animalName ;

    abstract public void Attack();
}
```

Comment: Can we see how `Animal` is defined?

Comment: When I write a complete, runnable Unity example based on your _incomplete_ example, it works fine -- that is, the `animalName` variable is correctly initialized at the statement in question when I look at it in the debugger.. You are either misinterpreting your observation (e.g. looking in the wrong place for the output of `Debug.Log()`...I note that this doesn't show up in my Application Output window in MonoDevelop), or you have failed to share some important detail.

Comment: @Peter Duniho In my code, I have a second Debug.Log() immediately following the one that isn't working, that reads `Debug.Log("test");` and it works fine.  If I open the console it's the only thing appearing, and if I remove it, the other Debug.Log() continues to display nothing.

Comment: @Peter Duniho I apologize.

Comment: @Asad I've added the code from the Animal superclass.

Comment: Still can't repro. The only irregularity I see in the code you posted is that your `Animal` class also has an `animalName` field, which you are hiding with the newly-declared `animalName` field in the `Sheep` class. As-is that would not explain the behavior you describe, but if the code you've posted is not _exactly_ what you're actually running it could. Probably what you really want is to not declare a new field at all, and instead initialize the base-class field in the `Sheep` constructor.

Comment: @Peter Duniho : I've created a constructor and moved the initialization of `animalName` there, and everything compiles and runs but still nothing appears in the console unless `animalName` is assigned within the `Attack()` class.  (Thank you, BTW, for noting that mistake).

Comment: Well, sorry but...you will need to figure out an actual [good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. I cannot reproduce the problem you describe using the code you've posted so far. The only way the code you've shown could produce the behavior you describe is a bug in the runtime; which I suppose is possible, depending on whether you are using the latest release of Unity or not (I'm testing this with 4.6.2f1).

Comment: @PeterDuniho : I'm running 5.01f1.  I don't think I can get any more minimal or complete with the code unless I am misunderstanding something (I suppose I can remove the integers from the Animal class). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Sheep` class so it looks like this:

```
public class Sheep : Animal {

    public Sheep()
    {
        animalName = "wot";
    }

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log(animalName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem. I even just went through and disabled all other objects and scripts in the hierarchy and it still doesn't show anything in the console.  Or, once I assign `animalName` (say, to "inAttack") within the `Attack()` method, run it to verify that it works that way, and move it back to the constructor, the next time I run the program, it still displays "inAttack" rather than "wot" in the console, from when `animalName` was assigned within `Attack()` as if Unity just isn't compiling that script at all when `animalName` is assigned in the constructor.

Comment: I think I maybe know what happened.  If you change a value in `Sheep` within the inspector, it seems to ignore what the code has set. Is this the case?  Because after I drag the script into an empty game object, those are all set, and any changes to the script I make afterwards seems to be immaterial.

Comment: @KeithWilson: it's possible. Unfortunately, Unity doesn't lend itself well to copy/paste code examples, but that's still the kind of detail needed. In this case, in lieu of a pastable code example, a _complete_ description of every step of creating a project from scratch might be useful (though of course tedious to provide and tedious to follow). But yes, if you set a value in the inspector, that would override any value you set in code. If you don't want to be able to change the value in the inspector, just make the field `readonly`.